# How to get a blank output for an integer from printf

Tags: c, io, int, printf, stdout

What value should be assigned to an integer in order to get a **blank value** displayed by `printf` in return when that integer is passed as an argument to it?

Although I assign a null value to the integer it prints 0

Can someone please suggest what can be done to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: If you want a blank output, don't use `printf`, just don't print anything if the integer is 0 or whatever.

Comment: You can't assign q null value to an int. If you have int x = 0; you have made x be zero, not null.

Comment: I agree with @not-Tony. Besides, you won't be able to have an integer print out a "blank". It'll most likely print out 0 (like you said) or the object's reference in memory. Instead, do this: if(num!=0){print.f("print whatever");}

Comment: Can you tell me a number that is represented with an empty string? I can't and you probably can't either. Since integers are numbers, what you want can't be achieved that way. However, if you take a step back and describe what you want to achieve on a higher level, you might get a few suggestions how to do that. Also, check out the problem with a so-called "XY problem", I think that's exactly what you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are instructing `printf()` to print an integer, there is no integer value that is represented by the empty string. There is no "null value" in the integer context, NULL in C is explicitly defined as being a zero value *in pointer context*. In integer context, `0` is simply a value. As for what should be done, use a conditional test to determine whether to call `printf()` or not, or use a conditional test to choose between using `printf()` to display an integer and using `printf()` (or another function) to display a string of spaces of some appropriate length.

Answer (score 1):

'Blank values' are (empty) strings and no integer can result in a blank value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no modifier for %d in printf to blank when zero; however, there are clearly times when you want to output blank for zeros in numerical output, specifically outputting a table of numbers where many are zero. If your set on using printf for this task then the following adjustment can be made to allow blanks when an int value is zero.

```
1   for (int i = 0; i < STOCKS; i++) {
2     char cur_str[4] = "   ";
3
4     if (current_price[i]) sprintf(cur_str, "%+3d", current_price[i]);
5
6     printf(pcb[i+4], "%-15s%4d   %4s     %4d",
7       stocks[i], ph[year-1][i], cur_str, ph[year][i]);    
8   }
```

Working backwards:
line 6-7 are the printf statement where the current price is to be displayed in the third column with the %4s option and corresponding *cur_str* argument

line 4 checks for a non-zero current price and uses sprintf to generate the right adjusted current price, when it is not zero, into *cur_str*

line 2 defaults *cur_str* to four spaces, the width of the column

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the integer to a string and then strip the (leading) zero before giving it to printf:

```
v1=42
v2=0
printf '%2s %2s\n' "${v1#0}" "${v2#0}"
```

This prints 42 for v1 and two blanks for v2.
Works fine in the Bourne shell or Bash.

Comment: The question is not about a shell.

Comment: printf is a built-in function of the Bourne shell (among other things).

Answer (score 0):

If there's a value you **100% absolutely** know will never be used in that context, use that value as meaning "blank" and define (and use) a `print_int_with_blank()` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IMPOSSIBLE_VALUE 42
int print_int_with_blank(char const *pre, int value, char const *post) {
    int n = 0;
    if (value != IMPOSSIBLE_VALUE) {
        n = printf("%s%d%s", pre, value, post);
    }
    return n;
}
```

And you may use it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = 7 * i;
    }
    print_int_with_blank("", a[0], "");
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        print_int_with_blank(", ", a[i], "");
    }
    puts("");
}
```

See [demo at ideone](http://ideone.com/5eManD)